# certificate creation on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

On Windows Server 2008 using RD Gateway Manager it is possible to create a SSL self-signed certificate. Which other ways exist to create certificates on Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 2):

You could install cygwin and openssl.

Answer (score 1):

Windows servers have a feature (or is it a role?) that you can install called Certificate Services. If you purchase an intermediate CA certificate, then you can issue certificates that are recognized by the greater internet. Or if you run a domain, you can issue certificates that members of your domain can trust.